# ValueError: A target array with shape (32, 5) was passed for an output of shape (None, 4) while using as loss categorical_crossentropy

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a model on a dataset of 40x40 grayscale images and I am getting this error:

**ValueError: A target array with shape (32, 5) was passed for an output of shape (None, 4) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.**

I don't know where the array of (32, 5) coming from as it should be (32, 4), so I didn't know what to change. Any suggestion?

````
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(#rescale = 1/255,
                                     shear_range = 0.3,
                                     zoom_range = 0.1,
                                     rotation_range = 30, 
                                     width_shift_range = 0.08, 
                                     height_shift_range = 0.08,
                                     horizontal_flip = True, 
                                     fill_mode = 'nearest',
                                    )

train_image_generator = image_generator.flow_from_directory('/data1/mypath/generated-images/train',
                                                            target_size = (40,40),
                                                            color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                            batch_size = 32,
                                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

test_image_generator = image_generator.flow_from_directory('/data1/mypath/generated-images/test',
                                                            target_size = (40,40),
                                                            color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                            batch_size = 32,
                                                            class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                            shuffle = False)


model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(40,40, 1), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=5)

model.fit_generator(train_image_generator, epochs=150,
                              validation_data = test_image_generator,
                              callbacks=[early_stopping]) ```
````

Comment: Can you please delete and post it in ai.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of classes in your dataset.

The array `(32,5)` is coming from the shape of your dataset.

The shape of Y(label), is showing as 5 classes, and you have declared it as 4 in the last output layer as `(None, 4)`. Which means the code is reading 4 classes from the image path provided.